# extract part of data from cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Ive got a load of html strings in cells in excel, what i want to do is extract the url from the string but lose the rest of the html markup.

the strings i have look like this

```
                <a class="text" href="http://cssrockstar.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/view/CSS Rockstar']);">CSS Rockstar</a>
```

all i need to extract is the `http://cssrockstar.com` part

i was trying to play around with some vba to do this but i got stuck pretty quickly, could some one point me in the right direction. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this with a formula (E3 would be your source cell).
This formula expects all href attributes to be delimited by double quotes.

```
=LEFT(MID(E3, FIND("href=""",E3)+6, 999),FIND("""",MID(E3, FIND("href=""",E3)+6, 999))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the **Split** function :

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "<a class=""text"" href=""http://cssrockstar.com"" target=""_blank"" rel=""nofollow"" onclick=""_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/view/CSS Rockstar']);"">CSS Rockstar</a>"

    Dim res As String
    res = Split(Split(Split(s, "href=")(1), " ")(0), """")(1)
End Sub
```